# VS Code launch.json to run and debug a MERN app

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, mern, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to setup my debug environment on VS Code to run and debug a MERN app.

I currently have this `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Node: Nodemon",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "dev"
      ],
      "outputCapture": "std",
    },
  ]
}
```

It's working just fine, but with it I can only have breakpoints in the backend and not in the React app on the frontend.

The script `yarn dev` (`package.json` in the backend) runs both backend and frontend with `concurrently`:

Here's my scripts in `package.json` in the backend:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node backend/server.js",
  "server": "nodemon backend/server.js",
  "client": "yarn --cwd frontend/ start",
  "dev": "concurrently \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
}
```

What would be a working `launch.json` that would allow me to have breakpoints in the frontend as well?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use VS Code's Multi-target debugging:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_multitarget-debugging

*"Using multi-target debugging is simple: after you've started a first debug session, you can just launch another session. As soon as a second session is up and running, the VS Code UI switches to multi-target mode".*

If you prefer to use launch.json, you can create a compound launch configuration, like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Node: Nodemon",
            "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "dev"
            ],
            "outputCapture": "std",
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Client",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/client.js"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Server/Client",
            "configurations": [
                "Node: Nodemon",
                "Client"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}",
            "stopAll": true
        }
    ]
}
```

The configurations will be launched in parallel.

Comment: I didn't quite get it to work unless first starting the frontend and attaching an edge or chrome debugger and then starting a debugger for the backend, but I really appreciate the "compounds" key which I didn't know!